# MySQL Workbench can't connect to any databases?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've tried connecting to a database through mySQL Workbench, but it didn't work.

It worked with the exact same configuration and database credentials on my laptop though. No I've tried it with a few others and it can't connect to them either.

Is it possible I'm missing some sort of driver or such? I'm not really sure what else to include and this question may be kinda vague, but I really need help with this.

If you need any more info just ask.

Comment: Maybe include the error you are getting!!?

Comment: if you are using ssh connection, remove known hosts file and try again.

Comment: It says it couldn't connect to the database with an error of "10060"

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if it's a Workbench or a general connection problem? 
Try this:

1. Open a terminal
2. Type `mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306`
3. If you can connect successfully you will see a mysql prompt after you type your password (type quit and Enter there to exit).

Here's the link for further stuff.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-connecting.html

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using Windows 10